# batch add leading zeroes filename

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, rename, filenames

I've got a script that I'm using for all kinds of things, including renaming and repacking comics. Variants of this script are used by others as well.

I've been seeing a limitation in repacking comics, however; I've found that some comics don't have the leading zeroes at their pages, which makes the pages appear out of order. So, I've added a part that should add leading zeroes.

The file does the following:

1. loop over all subfolders of the current folder
2. rename comic archives to their proper extension (so I can see where it is)
3. loop over all archives, and extract them to a temporary folder
4. loop over all files in the temporary folder, and add leading zeroes
5. repack it as a 7zip
6. rename the file to a comic book extension

Somehow, it's not renaming the files properly, and the name of the archive appears as a subfolder in the archive. For example:
let's repack 'testfolder', which contains images from 1 to 100. It renames, extracts, packs, and renames again, without problem. However, the new archive contains the folder named 'testfolder' in the archive next to the images, which don't have the leading zeroes. I'm not sure what's going on, and I've been fighting with it for a while now, so I thought to put it online (it's a good script to share, anyway). Does anyone have an idea on what's going wrong here?

```
@ECHO ON
rem mode con: cols=80 lines=60
for /f "delims=" %%F in ('dir /ad/s/b') do (
    cd %%F

    IF EXIST *.cbr (
        RENAME *.cbr *.rar
    )

    IF EXIST *.cbz (
        RENAME *.cbz *.zip
    )

    IF EXIST *.cb7 (
        RENAME *.cb7 *.7z
    )

    FOR %%I IN (*.RAR, *.ZIP *.7Z) DO (
        ECHO Extracting %%I...
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "%%I" -oC:\TMPPACKDIR\* -y | FIND /V "ing  "

        echo %%~nI
        cd C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI\

        FOR /f "delims=" %%P IN ('dir *.JPG, *.PNG, *.BMP') DO (
            SET %%N = %%P
            SET %%N = 00%%N
            SET %%N = %%N:~-2%
            echo %%P
            echo %%N
            pause
            rename 'C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI\%%P' %%N
        )

        pause

        echo %%F

        cd %%F

        ECHO Repacking
        "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%~nI.7z" "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI*" -mx=9 | FIND /V "ing  "

        IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 RD /S /Q C:\TMPPACKDIR

        ECHO Renaming new file
        RENAME *.7z *.CB7

        ECHO Removing original file
        DEL "%%I"
        ECHO File %%I is done
    )
)


REM del /f/q "%~0" | exit
```

Comment: You cannot assign `for` variables like `%%N`; you can only use a normal environment variable, like `set VAR=Value` (no spaces around `=`!); since you are in a parenthesised block of code (the `for` loop), you cannot access the variable like `%VAR%` but `!VAR!`; for this to work, you need to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) by placing `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` somewhere on top of your script...

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand; the whole script works fine, except for the part between cd C:\TMPPACKDIR\ and the PAUSE. I've removed the spaces around =, and added setlocal delayedexpansion to the top of the file, which seems to do 'something'; I'm getting 'file not found' somewhere in the third for loop, or perhaps in the loop call itself. The other loops work fine, though.

Comment: Right, I've changed the loop a bit (don't care about the filenames at all) the part now looks as follows:
`  echo Renaming images
  FOR /f "delims=" %%P IN ('dir "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI" /b ') DO (
   SET N=00%%P
   SET N=%%N:~-2%
   echo original name
   echo %%P
   echo new name
   echo %%N
   rename 'C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI\%%P' %%N
  )`
Which shows %%N to be '%N', and the rename command obviously fails.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43137962) below; normal environment variables are accessed by `%VAR%`, not `%%VAR`; but you need delayed expansion as already mentioned, so you have `!VAR!`; and do not use `''` to surround file paths, use `""` instead...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the problem is in the code portion between `cd C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI\` and `pause`. You are trying to set a `for` variable reference `%%N`, which does not work. You need to use a normal environment variable instead, like `NAME`, for example; you can only do sub-string expansion (like `~-2` in your code) using normal environment variables. In addition, since you are setting and reading the same environment variable within a single block of code, you need to use [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); otherwise, you would always receive the value present when the entire block is read.

The code portion should look like this:

```cmd
        cd /D "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI"

        for /F "delims=" %%P in ('dir /B *.JPG, *.PNG, *.BMP') do (
            set "FILE=C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI\%%P"
            set "NAME=00%%~nP"
            setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
            set "NAME=!NAME:~-2!"
            rename "!FILE!" "!NAME!%%~xP"
            endlocal
        )

        pause
```

Comment: That seems to have gotten me quite a ways further. The for-loop you specified (the first line) leads to a boatload of 'cannot find the file specified', but
`FOR /f "delims=" %%P IN ('dir "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI" /b ') DO (`
seems to work just fine (and doesn't care about the file type, which is good as well)

I'm not quite sure why your line doesn't find the files, and am still not sure where the empty folder comes from, but at least the script produces archives that I can use further. Thanks!

Comment: Seems I have forgotten the `/B` option at the [`dir` command](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html)...

Answer (score 1):

I've removed some unnecessary stuff and made a few changes, *(the main error being that which aschipfl has already identified)*.

```bat
FOR /F "DELIMS=" %%F IN ('DIR/AD/S/B') DO (
    PUSHD "%%F"
    IF EXIST *.cbr REN *.cbr *.rar
    IF EXIST *.cbz REN *.cbz *.zip
    IF EXIST *.cb7 REN *.cb7 *.7z
    FOR %%I IN (*.RAR, *.ZIP *.7Z) DO (
        ECHO Extracting %%I...
        "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" e "%%I" -o"C:\TMPPACKDIR\*" -y
        PUSHD "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI"
        FOR %%P IN (*.JPG, *.PNG, *.BMP) DO (
            SET "_N=100%%~nP"
            SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
            SET "_N=!_N:~-2!"
            REN "%%P" "!_N!%%~xP"
            ENDLOCAL
        )
        POPD
        ECHO Repacking
        "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -t7z "%%~nI.7z" "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI*" -mx=9
        IF NOT ERRORLEVEL 1 RD/S/Q "C:\TMPPACKDIR\%%~nI"
        ECHO Renaming new file
        REN "%%~nI.7z" "%%~nI.CB7"
        ECHO Removing original file
        DEL "%%I"
        ECHO File %%I is done
    )
    POPD
)
```

*Things to look into:
Can `7z.exe` not just extract .cbr, .cbz & .cb7 directly without renaming them first. In the same way, when repacking once you've provided the file type, `-t7z` can the file not be given the name `"%%~nI.CB7"` directly instead of later renaming it.*